# The $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ vectorspace has a linear transformation, which kernel and image is also two dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ vectorspace has a linear transformation, which kernel and image is also two dimensional.

I think that this isn't true, but I still don't have any counter example or should I maybe check the definitions of the kernel and image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L$ is a linear transformation on a vector space $V$, then: $$\dim\ker L+\dim\mbox{im} L=\dim V . $$

But $2+2\ne3$.

Comment: so if the kernel and the image would be also two dimensional, than the vectorspace has to be in the vectorspace of $ \mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: or maybe in higher dimensions

Comment: $4$ dimensional space, not higher dimension. What do you mean with "vectorspace has to be in the vectorspace of $\mathbb R^4$

Comment: just writing the justification very "primitve" from the thesis above: $2+2=4$ and $2+2 $ is not equal to $3$